# Excel VBA: Insert new row in multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform where the user inputs data and then clicks the button Add.
The VBA then creates a new row and inputs the data from the user into that row.
This works fine, however I want to also add a new row in a different sheet as well and this is where I am stuck.

This is my code:

```html
Dim i As String
Dim j As String
Dim k As String
Dim m As String
Dim n As String
j = XIDBox.Value
i = OrgNameBox.Value
k = ContactNameBox.Value
m = PhoneBox.Value
n = EmailBox.Value

dstRw = Sheets("Input Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Sheets("Input Data").Cells(dstRw, 1).Value = i
Sheets("Input Data").Cells(dstRw, 2).Value = j
Sheets("Input Data").Cells(dstRw, 4).Value = k
Sheets("Input Data").Cells(dstRw, 6).Value = m
Sheets("Input Data").Cells(dstRw, 5).Value = n

'Here I want a code that inserts a blank row just as dstRw does above but in a different sheet.
```

Comment: Have you tried changing your sheet reference from this line `dstRw = Sheets("Input Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1` and adding it again at the bottom?

Comment: Yes I tried that but it did not add any new row to the sheet.

Comment: You need to change the row reference as well and use the `.Insert` function as Jason noted in his answer.

Comment: Are you trying to extend the range of a table?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to extend the range of a table

Comment: Then you can use `Sheets("Input Data").ListObjects("Table2").Resize Range("$A$1:$F$5")`. Change the sheet name, table name, and range reference as necessary. I'll post as an answer if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process is very similar to what you have in place.

```
'Here I want a code that inserts a blank row just as dstRw does above but in a different sheet.
Dim otherSheet As Worksheet
Set otherSheet = Sheets("Other Sheet Name")

' Insert as the last row.
Dim otherRow As Long
otherRow = otherSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

' Now write the values.
otherSheet.Cells(otherRow, 1).Value = i
otherSheet.Cells(otherRow, 2).Value = j
otherSheet.Cells(otherRow, 4).Value = k
otherSheet.Cells(otherRow, 6).Value = m
otherSheet.Cells(otherRow, 5).Value = n
```

Comment: I need it to find the last row in a table and add the new row below that and then input the data. I believe in your example there is a specific row referenced?

Comment: Thanks for your edit, it is working as intended now!

Answer (score 0):

This works for both sheets using an array for your sheets.  You can expand it by adding items to the array in the same manner.  You also don't need to store the values as variables, since the name of the object is small, you can just set the cell's values directly from the source.

This finds the last row for each sheet, adds 1 and then sets the values of the cells from your source objects.  Then loops the process for the next sheet in the array.

**TESTED:**

```
Sub ValueMove()

Dim dstRw As Long
Dim sheet(1) As String

    sheet(0) = "Input Data"
    sheet(1) = "Different Sheet"

    For s = 0 To 1

        dstRw = Sheets(sheet(s)).Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1

        Sheets(sheet(s)).Cells(dstRw, 1).Value = OrgNameBox.Value
        Sheets(sheet(s)).Cells(dstRw, 2).Value = XIDBox.Value
        Sheets(sheet(s)).Cells(dstRw, 4).Value = ContactNameBox.Value
        Sheets(sheet(s)).Cells(dstRw, 6).Value = PhoneBox.Value
        Sheets(sheet(s)).Cells(dstRw, 5).Value = EmailBox.Value
    Next s

End Sub
```